# Centre relative to height when on 3.5 inch iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

Ok, so I want the positioning of the items in a view to re centre when going from 4 inch screen to 3.5 inch screen. How do I do this.

I've attached pictures for what it looks like on a 4 inch screen and what it looks like on a 3.5 inch screen.

Image 1:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2KtI.png
  Image 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1TLb.png

So image 1 is the 3.5 inch version and 2 is the 4 inch version. As you can see on the 4 inch screen, all the items in the view are in the centre relative to the height. I want it to be in the centre for the 3.5 inch screen as well. How do I do this with autolayout?

Answer (score 0):

If you're programmatically implementing the objects you could easily change the placement for the screen size based around the self.view.frame.size.height. You could take that information and correctly place your objects in the center by doing some basic math.

If you're using storyboards you can use autolayout to set constraints in IB to have all of the items stay where you want them relative to the screen size. When you select an item on your scene you can easily add autolayout constraints by going to Editor -> Resolve Autolayout Issues -> Add Missing Constraints.

Remember that if you are using storyboard's you can change which screen size you're viewing. In the bottom right of IB there are a selection of buttons and the one on the far left toggles between 4" and 3.5" screen sizes.

Comment: When I add missing constraints for all the items in the scene, it just keeps them in the same position, it doesn't move the items, it just keeps them in the same place relative to each other. I want the items to move to the relative centre position depending on the size of the screen. So for the 3.5 inch screen, everything should be move up a bit to make it centred relative to the height. Is that possible?